# Change value in array zend framework

Tags: php, arrays

I'm struggling with my array. I get a array like this:

```
Array
(
    [state] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [state] => 1
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [state] => 2
                    )

            )
)
```

I want to change the 1 to 'active' and the 2 to 'inactive'.
I've allready a controller which get this 1 and 2. Controller look likes:

```
if ($name == 'state') {
    foreach ($dropdownArray[$name] as $arrayName) {
        if ($arrayName[$name] == '1') {
            echo $arrayName[$name];
            $arrayName[$name] = 'active';
        } else {
            echo $arrayName[$name];
            $arrayName[$name] = 'inactive';
        }
    }
 }
```

With $name I get the value from the dropdown field. So in this case $name = state.

As expected, I get the 1 and 2 in an echo. So he get the good values. But how to set this values to Active and Inactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $dropdownArray[$name] instead of $arrayName[$name] like that

```
foreach ($dropdownArray[$name] as $key=>$arrayName) {
    if ($arrayName[$name] == '1') {
        $dropdownArray[$name][$key][$name] = 'active';
    } else {
        $dropdownArray[$name][$key][$name] = 'inactive';
    }
}
```